venvの環境を削除したのでプロンプトから.venvの文字列を消したい
開発環境
ChromeOS（crostini）のDebian12に追加したUbuntu24.04のDockerコンテナ
Python3.12
発生している事象
VSCode内のターミナルで、Pythonのプロジェクトのディレクトリにインストールしたvenvの仮想環境を削除とdeactivateする
そして、VSCodeのターミナルを再起動した場合、プロンプトの左端に.venvという文字列が残ってしまっている
(.venv)<ユーザー名>@<ホスト名>~:$

試行錯誤したこと
Pythonを使ったプロジェクト内からvenvで作った仮想環境をrm -r .venvで削除したあと、deactivateした
期待していること
deactivateしたあとにDockerを再起動してプロジェクトのディレクトリに
入ったときに、プロンプトが下のようになること
<ユーザー名>@<ホスト名>~:$


公式ドキュメントより venv --- 仮想環境の作成

シェルで "deactivate" と入力することで仮想環境を無効化できます。 厳密な仕組みはプラットフォーム固有であり、内部の実装詳細です (たいていはスクリプトかシェル関数が使われます)。


プロンプトどころか、 PATH の情報も残ったままですが、それを含めて activate を実行する前の状態に戻したいのであれば、 deactivate コマンドを実行してください。
